# How to create a table with a filter?

Tags: 7, theming

I am using drupal 7

The following code turns an array into a pagered table.

```
$rows = $data[data];
$per_page = 30;
// Initialize the pager
$current_page = pager_default_initialize(count($rows), $per_page);
// Split your list into page sized chunks
$chunks = array_chunk($rows, $per_page, TRUE);
// Show the appropriate items from the list
$output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $chunks[$current_page]));
// Show the pager
$output .= theme('pager', array('quantity',count($rows)));
echo $output;
```

Is it possible to add filters to the table?

Thanks

Updated 21/04/2016 as Per Neograph734s answer

I have built a module based around the code Neograph734 gave as an example.

My array is built like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [EventTime] => 23/04/2016 15:00
            [EventType] => Foo
            [EventName] => Bar 
            [EventRating] => 99.12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [EventTime] => 23/04/2016 18:00
            [EventType] => FooFoo
            [EventName] => BarBar 
            [EventRating] => 94.84
        )
```

The only ammendment I have made is in field to seach as below

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
  if (preg_match("/" . $form_state['storage']['title'] . "/", $row['EventName'])) {
    $temp_rows[$key] = $row;
  }
}
```

The table initially loads, I have a text area and a submit button. When I enter a search term the page reloads but the table does not filter, it still shows all results.

The html out put is

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>23/04/2016 15:00</td>
<td>Foo</td>
<td>Bar</td>
<td>99.12</td>
</tr>
```

What more do I have to change to get the text field to search the results?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be programmatically? You can use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to output a table with filters.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting my data externally through an API. I don't know if there's a way for views to output an array.

Comment: That would be possible, but would involve even more code. So not your best option then.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by wrapping your table in a form, and then use the form API to render your table and re-render it on submit. You can have a look at this comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1770512#comment-6428358

In short the render funtion:

```
function MY_MODULE_build_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // Filter field.
  $form['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Title to look for'),
    '#size' => 15,
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['storage']['title']) ? $form_state['storage']['title'] : '',
  );

  // Submit button.
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t("Find"),  
  );

  // Modify table array here. 
  // If your API supports filters, you can use that too. 
  // My regex is bad, so you might need to tweak this.
  if (isset($form_state['storage']['title'])) {
    $temp_rows = array();

    foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
      if (preg_match("/" . $form_state['storage']['title'] . "/", $row['field_to_search'])) {
        $temp_rows[$key] = $row;
      }
    }

    $rows = $temp_rows;
  }

  // Render the table array.
  $form['table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#empty' => t('Empty Rows')
  );      

  return $form;
}
```

And the Submit function

```
function MY_MODULE_build_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Set the provided filter value in the storage.
  $form_state['storage']['title'] = $form_state['values']['title'];
  // Show the form again.
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;  
}
```

You might want to fancy it up with some fieldsets, but those are left out to keep the answer understandable.

Comment: Hi thanks for the starting point, I have the table and search field in a form but the table does not filter. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @SamHealey, you should add some debug code to see if the submit functions is getting called and `$form_state['storage']['title']` actually receives the value of `$form_state['values']['title']`. Install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and use the `dpm()` function to read `$form_state` during the submit.

Answer (score 1):

[DataTables module](https://www.drupal.org/project/datatables) offers you a theming function (see *theme_datatable* in your source) or a views formatter.

> It is a quite handy and popular jQuery table sort/filter/pagination plugin

**But only client-side !** If you want the filter data server-side you need to use the form API too.

You can overwrite DataTables module [behavior](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/datatables/tree/js/datatables.js?id=9954c09) in your theme to initialize the jQuery plugins according your needs.